# Disable freehand drawing in draw interaction in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, draw-interaction

I have this:

```
draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
        source: drawVector.getSource(),
        type: "LineString",
        freehand: false,
        finishCondition: function(event) {
            return false;
          }
});
```

It should not allow you to draw in freehand mode but if I press shift it lets me do so. How can I completly remove that option?

Comment: `freehandCondition: ol.events.condition.never,`

Comment: The problem with it is that the lines disapear when i do finishDrawing

Comment: It works for me https://codesandbox.io/s/draw-features-forked-7coy48?file=/main.js

Comment: Yeah, it works, i changed the finishCondition to the same thing and it worked, don´t know what it has to do with freehand tho, but the important thing is it worked, thanks